# What songs start on a minor second chord?

Tags: chords

I came across the song El Shaddai (

) and was amazed that such a natural sounding melody started on the minor second chord. I can't think of any other songs that do that, and a google search isn't helping. Do any of you know other songs that start on the minor second?

Comment: It depends on how you define "starting" but "I've Got You under My Skin" has the first emphasized beat of the A section as a ii7.

Comment: I guess I should clarify. I'm using starting to mean the first chord of the main melody, not counting the lead in.

Comment: Then what I mentioned fits. But it's the only one I can think of off-hand.

Comment: Beatles All My Lovin'. Rod Stewart 'I Don't Want to Talk About It'. Lollipops and Roses. The list goes on. Isn't it often one of the well used jazz sequences - ii>V>I?

Comment: @Tim Isn't your comment an answer already? :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz - yes, but we don't do lists of songs for answers on this site. It's not what the site is about. The question will likely be closed. Check reasons for closure.

Comment: @Tim - I didn't know about that rule, but I'm not sure where else to ask this. I don't know jazz that well, to me the melodies seem forced so I don't listen to too much. I'll check out those songs, though. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

'Satin Doll'.  As already mentioned in a comment, 'I've Got You under My Skin'. 'By the Time I Get to Phoenix'. 'All My Loving'.  Want some more?